# Mobile Push message history with ampscript processed

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, mobilepush

One of our customer want's to access the history of mobile messages deployed to subscribers. Some of the messages on this account are complex and are built using ampscript, Simplifying, they look something like this (example, not actual message):

```
BRAND confirms reservation number %%=AttributeValue('Reservation__c:Name')=%% on %%=AttributeValue('Reservation__c:Date__c')=%%. Salon address is %%=AttributeValue('Reservation__c:Address__c')=%%.
```

This renders to:

```
BRAND confirms reservation number 123456 on 05/05/2019 12:30. Salon address is ul. Warszawaska 2, Warsaw.
```

Looking through Customer Messages history in All Contacts or with Push Message Detailed Report Extract, all messages are shown in its unrendered form containing ampscript instead text sent to subscriber.

I'm looking for a way to get a history of actual messages sent to subscribers, not ampscript code used for this send. Does anyone know if it's easily achievable for messages already deployed and available in some bulk export?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Marketing Cloud doesn't store copy of render messages (email/sms/push) You would need to leverage a [send log](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_mp_send_logging.htm&type=5) for future messages to capture the attributevalues used at send time. This is outlined in the help page '[Send Logging](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_send_logging.htm&type=5)'

> To keep additional information in the send logging data extension, create a column in the data extension to contain it. The names of the columns in the send logging data extension must exactly match the names of the attributes or the fields in the sendable data extensions to log any values.

Comment: I'm familiar with send logging and I created one for Mobile Push messages. Issue described is about messages already deployed, as these were sent before creation of the log.

Comment: Since the render message is not stored in MC there is no way to export it

Comment: What about clicking your message template in Mobile Connect (with some sends related to one) => Create Report => Show all data (no filter) => the CSV file will contain rendered messages. @EazyE